# Ansible incorrectly removes IP ranges from Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I've done an Ansible run this morning to change firewall rules for an AWS Security Group.

I was surprised to see that instead of adding 2 IP ranges, running the ec2_group module removed 10 out of the 25 IP ranges.

[image]

```
tasks:
- name: Create security group HTTPS Access
  ec2_group:
    name: "HTTPS-ELB"
    description: "Ranges for main ELB HTTPS"
    vpc_id: "vpc-"
    region: "eu-west-1"
    rules:
    - proto: tcp
      from_port: 443
      to_port: 443
      cidr_ip: 131.x.x.0/24
    .. 24 more rules
```

CloudTrail from AWS shows however this JSON the first run for 10 out of 25 ranges:

```
"eventName": "RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
"awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
"userAgent": "Boto/2.38.0 Python/2.7.6 Darwin/14.4.0",
"requestParameters": {
    "groupId": "sg-",
    "ipPermissions": {
        "items": [
            {
                "ipProtocol": "tcp",
                "fromPort": 443,
                "toPort": 443,
                "groups": {},
                "ipRanges": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "cidrIp": "131.x.x.0/24"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "prefixListIds": {}
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

I reran the same playbook again with the same list of 25 IP ranges and that fixed it. Any tips here to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it was caused by a bug in the ec2_group module.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/698